# postmark email sends from command line but not AJAX even though AJAX returning 200?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, request

I am sending emails by postmark through terminal and it works. I want a client only website with no maintenance and only happy times.

```
curl "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Postmark-Server-Token: 555-5555-555" \
  -d "{From: 'info@pythondevhouse.com', To: 'cchilder@mail.usf.edu', Subject: 'Hello from Postmark', HtmlBody: '<strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.'}"
```

I adapted an ajax call like so:

```
$('.new-email-button').click(function() {

    var fromEmail = $('.email').val();
    console.log('email');
    console.log(fromEmail);
    var message = $('.email-message').val();
    console.log(message);
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (re.test(fromEmail)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email",
            data: {
              "From": "info@pythondevhouse.com",
              "To": "cchilder@mail.usf.edu",
              "Cc": "copied@example.com",
              "Bcc": "blank-copied@example.com",
              "Subject": "Test",
              "Tag": "Invitation",
              "TextBody": message,
              "ReplyTo": fromEmail,
              "Headers": [
                { 
                "Name": "X-Postmark-Server-Token",
                "Value": "ba7663a2-19ba-4a42-bf69-5b4485fcab6f"
                  }
              ],
              "TrackOpens": true
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            accepts: {
                text: "application/json"
            }

           }).done(function(response) {
             alert(response);
             if (response[0].status == 'rejected'){
               alert("I'm sorry, the email form isn't working.\n\nPlease email info@pythondevhouse.com\nor call 813-555-5555");
             }
             else{
               alert("Sent successfully! Thank you, I will contact you soon");
               console.log(response); // I am.
             }
             if(response[0].status === "sent") {
               $('.email').val('');
               $('.email-message').val('');
             }
           });
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Email Address");
      }
});
```

Terminal send works immediately, AJAX on my site is getting 200 but not sending. I can see an error here (this was local machine):

[image]

following the fixes suggested fail:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://codyc4321.github.io",
        }
        ...
```

Adding this allow makes the entire function silently fail, and I no longer get an email request, nor an error, which seems to make no sense.  So I remove this header and get an error saying I didn't give it the thing I just gave it! What is this, a job interview or dating?! I just gave it what it asked for. So I remove `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` header and get:

[image]

Please help me send email based on this error:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: this problem occurs in modern browsers when cross-domain request are happening `(http to https or https to http)` now a days for security issue. I also want to know the solution

Comment: The api doesn't support CORS so you cant use ajax to call it. You have to make the call to the api on your server.

Comment: A web search of that error will explain the whole issue. It comes up here many times a day also

Comment: I'm not sure a web search works lol, I've been reading about it for hours today and each answer that comes back is random and either poorly explained or using languages I don't wanna learn right now